# How to pass a integer using performSelectorInBackground

Tags: objective-c, syntax

I don't want to passAnInt with object. Can I pass it with Int only? if not , how can I do so? Thank you.

```
[myController performSelectorInBackground:@selector(passAnInt:) withObject:int];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can box the `int` within an NSNumber. If your method signature is:

```
- (void)passAnInt:(NSNumber *)someNumber;
```

Then you can call it using:

```
int someInt = 5;
NSNumber *num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:someInt];
[myController performSelectorInBackground:@selector(passAnInt:) withObject:num];
```

Then, in your method, you can get the `int` back out again using NSNumber's `intValue` method. See the [NSNumber class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more.

Comment: and how can I pass the NSNumber to int?

Comment: @Tim Thank you very much. I noticed that I had a bug with my one of my methods which was taking in a NSNumber but I wasn't sure what was wrong.